# How can I embed a local image in gmail without using an external link?

Tags: gmail, images

In Gmail, I can only cut and paste a picture from the web into the mail, but even then when it arrives in someone's Thunderbird, for instance, they have to click "show remote content" to see it embedded.

I can attach a local image to the email, but I want it embedded within the text of the mail.

Googling an answer tells me that I should "Click the Insert Image button in the message's formatting toolbar." but in the latest version of Gmail there is no "insert image button":

[image]

**How can I embed a local image from my hard drive into a Gmail e-mail so that e.g. Thunderbird can see it embedded without clicking a "load remote content" button?**

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Google in their infinite wisdom have made the feature an option through the Gmail Labs. [This support page](http://support.google.com/mail/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=148408&topic=1669035&ctx=topic) details the procedure to enable it:

> 1. Click the gear icon  in the upper right, then select Settings.
> 2. Select the Labs tab.
> 3. Select the 'Enable' button next to 'Inserting images'.
> 4. Click Save.
> 5. When you're composing a message, you'll see an icon in the Gmail toolbar, between the "Insert emoticon" (smiley face) and "Link" buttons. Click that to insert an image.

You can add either a URL or a file you've saved to your computer - however only adding from your computer will attach the file to the email.